# C# embedding test code inside a console app

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest, xunit

Is it possible to embed test code (based on one of the MSTEST, NUNIT, or XUNIT) inside a dotnet core console app?

Based on the tutorials like the one below, it seems there is the requirement that the test code has always to be a separate project than the actual project.

I understand some of the cons of embedding testing code in the actual project, but I really don’t want to turn many of the internal classes to public, or adding the InternalTo attribute everywhere, just to make them accessible to the test code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always create new project for Unit Tests, but you can have Unit Tests in your Console Application.

Just for demo purposes, I've added all the classes in one single file.

[image: Example:]

If you don't want your tests on production, you can surround your test classes with the #if DEBUG and #endif.

This way, it will compile on debug mode and be ignored on release mode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you use NUnit 3 like i did in my example, you can download the NUnit console tool at https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases/tag/3.8 (Download and extract NUnit.Console-3.8.0.zip, e.g.).

The run the tool agains your executable file, example:
nunit3-console.exe "D:\path_to_your_console_application\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NUnitLite to create an executable test program, which runs your tests. Link to both the nunit framework and the corresponding version of nunitlite and write a Main following these instructions: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/nunitlite/AutoRun.cs#L34